# can't use paginate when use sortby in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I Want to get products and sort it by `mutator attribute` in my case it's called `price`

i search for how to sort it and found that i can use `sortBy` from the `collection`

like that

```
private function search()
{   
    return Product::with(['firstImage', 'category'])
        ->sortBy('price');
}
```

it works fine, but when I try to add `paginate` nothing happens and there is no paginate in the response

```
private function search()
{   
    return Product::with(['firstImage', 'category'])
        ->paginate(9)->sortBy('price');

}
```

So how can i add `paginate` in this case?

**Edit**

`price` mutator

```
public function getPriceAttribute()
{
    return $this->sell_price - (($this->discount * $this->sell_price) / 100);
}
```

Comment: The edit come from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764101/how-to-paginate-after-a-sort-by-in-laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to call `paginate()` on collection. You may manually paginate the collection result or modify your query and use `addSelect` or `orderByRaw` to include mutated value:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Product::select('*', DB::raw('(sell_price - ((discount * sell_price) / 100)) AS price'))
        ->orderBy('price')
        ->paginate(9);
```

By the way, I think you'll get the same result to order by `sell_price` column instead of `price` mutated value if your discount is a constant value, so try `orderBy('sell_price')` instead of `sortBy('price')`:

```php
Product::with(['firstImage', 'category'])
        ->orderBy('sell_price')
        ->paginate(9);
```

Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: it works for real attributes only as i mentioned before the `price` attribute not real one it is mutator

Comment: @Joseph Don't you get the same result if you order by `sell_price` instead? You are subtracting a discount percent from the sell price to get price. I believe you get the same result, am I wrong?

Comment: you are right but i made this nutator to contain all the logic in one place, but i think that i will write this logic the query itself as you mention

Answer (score 2):

You must use `paginate(9)` after `orderBy()` function.
So you must edit second code like this :

```
private function search()
{   
    return Product::with(['firstImage', 'category'])
        ->orderBy('price')->paginate(9);

}
```

Comment: `paginate` method does not exist in the `collection` instance

Comment: @Joseph I saw your comment very late but now I changed my answer thanks. but still, you can not use sortBy after paginate.